# Event USB detection with udevadm monitor

Tags: c++, c, linux, usb

My purpose is to detect the event generated after the detection/remove of a USB.( OS:Linux and language C/C++).
for that , I used the package Udevadm to get this event, and I get the output below:

```
UDEV  [9494.049740] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-WIKO_Mass_Storage_0123456789ABCDEF-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:02:03.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/block/sdb
DEVTYPE=disk
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=Mass_Storage
ID_MODEL_ENC=Mass\x20Storage\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=0001
ID_PATH=pci-0000:02:03.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_02_03_0-usb-0_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=0000
ID_SERIAL=WIKO_Mass_Storage_0123456789ABCDEF-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0123456789ABCDEF
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=WIKO
ID_VENDOR_ENC=WIKO\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_VENDOR_ID=0bb4
MAJOR=8
MINOR=16
SEQNUM=2394
SUBSYSTEM=block
UDEV_LOG=3
UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
USEC_INITIALIZED=9493993109
```

Is there a way to get the type of "the event", the "Action", and the "DEVNAME", without parsing all the output in variable String and after that collect the important information?

Comment: There is no language C/C++, there is C and there is C++.

Comment: Yes, such way is exists

Comment: @ Baum mit Augen i'm not stupid as you thing ....i'm not comming from the planet Mars.....i know that the is of course language C and Language C++.....so please Mrs @Baum mit Augen be serious or shut up..

Comment: I am little unclear about your requirement. What I am understanding is you want specific fields from above output. If that is so you can filter the output using grep, something like grep "ACTION"|"DEVNAME" and redirect to file or assign to a variable. You can then separate the fields for use. This is scripting way. Or probably then use system() call to execute the same shell command from C code.